# To print a hashmap where key is employee number and value is arraylist

Tags: java

```
    Employee e = new Employee();
    String eno=e.getEno();
    HashMap<String,ArrayList<Employee>> map = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<Employee>>();
    ArrayList<Employee> al = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    Employee e1=new Employee("1001","Rahul", "Gupta", "agupta");
    Employee e2=new Employee("1002","Bijay", "Gupta", "bjay");
    al.add(e1);
    al.add(e2);
    map.put(eno, al);
    for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Employee>> entry : map.entrySet()) {

        String key = entry.getKey();

        ArrayList<Employee> values = entry.getValue();

        System.out.println("Key = " + key);

        System.out.println("Values = " + values + "n");

    }
```

I am getting key a null whereas I want print
Eno.as key and value as eno,fname,lname and emailid

Comment: Kindly do some study on your own! Put your efforts its pretty basic task!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @Zubair, `getEno()` is not set, so it returns null.

If you want to print emp no as key and value as eno,fname,lname and emailid, I would suggest:

```
HashMap<String,Employee> map = new HashMap<String,Employee>();

Employee e1=new Employee("1001","Rahul", "Gupta", "agupta");
Employee e2=new Employee("1002","Bijay", "Gupta", "bjay");

map.put(e1.getEno(), e1);
map.put(e2.getEno(), e2);
for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Employee>> entry : map.entrySet()) {

    String key = entry.getKey();

    Employee value = entry.getValue();

    System.out.println("Key = " + key);

    System.out.println("Values = " + value.getEno() + " "+ value.getFname()+" "+value.getLname()+" "+getEmailid());

}
```

Or, you can override toString() in Employee class and then write:

```
System.out.println(value.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

That is becasue you are doing.

```
Employee e = new Employee();
String eno=e.getEno();
```

here eno is null, as you are creating a new Employee object.
Assign eno as any value first. You can ask for any help, if you need.
Enjoy coding